# Micrófono en un WebView

Tags: android, webview, permisos

Estoy tratando acceder al micrófono desde un `WebView` y me dice que necesito `android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS`, pero ya lo tengo entre los permisos del `Manifest`.

Comment: Considera agregar el código que estas realizando, en tu pregunta, así como como defines el permiso, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: El código en MainActivity es: 
    `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    `
Lo demás es javascript.

Comment: I think I've solved it, but now I get "Uncaught (in promise) NotAllowedError: Permission denied". I'm not if the problem is related though.

Comment: Perdón, me olvidé que este era el foro en español. Aparentemente, solucioné la primera parte, pero ahora me da "Uncaught (in promise) NotAllowedError: Permission denied".

Comment: Aparentemente tiene que ver con que el webview bloquea el mensaje file///: quiere Utilizar el micrófono. Angluna idea?